# How to add dependencies using gradle? "Could not find method repositories() for arguments"

Tags: java, gradle

I just added `repositories` and `dependencies` manually to my `settings.gradle` file (doesn't gradle have a CLI for doing this?)

Now my `settings.gradle` looks like

```
plugins {
    // Apply the foojay-resolver plugin to allow automatic download of JDKs
    id 'org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention' version '0.4.0'
}

rootProject.name = 'demo'
include('lib')

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.1.1'
}
```

When I `gradle build` I get this error

> Could not find method repositories() for arguments [settings_9q38hxd1yon6ul6yzwrcvaoie$_run_closure1@6bfa1f1a] on settings 'demo' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings

How am I meant to add dependencies to gradle?

Comment: I think file name should be `build.gradle` and not `settings.gradle`. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mixed up the purpose of the files.
The main difference between `settings.gradle` and `lib/build.gradle` lies in their scope and purpose:

- `settings.gradle` defines the global project settings and project structure, applied globally to all modules in the project.
- `lib/build.gradle` contains build script instructions and settings specific to a particular module.

In your case, these files should be like this.

1. `settings.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention' version '0.5.0'
}

rootProject.name = 'demo'
include('lib')
```

2. `lib/build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.1.1'
}
```

And make sure you are using `gradle` version 7.6.1+

I hope this helps you. Good luck!

Comment: `gradle init` didn't make me a `build.gradle` file, and it put `plugins` into `settings.gradle` itself.

Comment: I tried your setup and now I get the error Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.1.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Comment: You was right. I found this in [doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html#sub:download_repositories)

Just move `org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention` plugin to `settings.gradle`
and in `build.gradle` file leave 
- plugins {id 'java'}
- repositories
- dependencies

and make sure you are using `gradle` version 7.6.1+

Comment: Do you know what the `java` plugin is?

Comment: @minseong The `java` plugin in Gradle provides tasks for compiling, testing, managing dependencies, and other. You can read about it [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html)